# Prevent the doctrine postLoad event for some cases

Tags: symfony, events, doctrine

I have an entity `BlogPost` with a `status` property. This status property depends on an external API call which is handled via the doctrine postLoad event. All other properties are stored in the local database.

```
public function postLoad(BlogPost $post)
{
    $this->postHandler->calculateStatus($post);
}
```

The problem is, in some cases i don't want to calculate the status at all. For example if i want to get only the `description` of all blogposts.

With the code above, all blog entities being loaded will trigger the postLoad event even if i just want to have values from a local database. That is very expensive and not acceptable.

So for example in my repository class i want to get all BlogPosts having a website without invoking the postLoad event.

```
public function findBlogPosts()
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('bp')
        ->from('AppBundle:BlogPosts', 'bp')
        ->innerJoin('bp.website', 'w');
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Is there a way to say "Yes, load the BlogPost collection, but do not fire event!" ???

Any other approaches? Custom event?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i haven't found a real similar use case on the internet, i'll go for the following solution which seems the easiest and most acceptable cleanest to me. Maybe someone else could find this useful.

1. Implement a `TransientLoadable` Interface

   ```
   interface TransientLoadable
   {
       public function isLoaded() : bool;
       public function setLoaded(bool $loaded) : TransientLoadable;
       public function setTransientLoadingFunction(\Closure $loadingFunction) :
       TransientLoadable;
   }
   ```
2. Implement the entity

   ```
   class BlogPost implements TransientLoadable
   {
    ...
   }
   ```
3. Setup Loading function on postLoad Event

   ```
   public function postLoad(BlogPost $post)
   {
       $func = function() use ($postHandler, $post) 
       {
           //Since there may be another fields being loaded from the same API, catch them also since data is anyway in the same request
           $postHandler->setAllDataFromAPI($post)
           //Set the loading state to true to prevent calling the API again for the next property which may also be transient
           $post->setLoaded(true);
       }
       $post->setTransientLoadingFunction($func)
   }
   ```
4. Use the built-in lazy loading mechanism to get the property from the API only when it's needed

   ```
   class BlogPost implements TransientLoadable
   {
        private function getStatus() : int
        {
            if (!$this->isLoaded) {
                call_user_function($this->loadingFunction)
            }
            return $this->status;
        }

        private function getVisitorCount() : int
        {
            if (!$this->isLoaded) {
                call_user_function($this->loadingFunction)
            }
            return $this->visitorCount;
        }
   }
   ```

So what's happening? Let's imagine we want to get the status and the visitor count, both are loaded via a single external API call.

If some api-dependent property of the entity is needed, all other properties gets loaded too (since we don't want to have for each property another call). This in ensured through the `loaded` function of the `TransientLoadable` interface. All data gets loaded by the `setAllDataFromAPI` function which is injected as a closure function.

I think that is not the cleanest solution. The loading stuf should be done by an extra layer on top of the entity class. Since sonata admin does not deal with such an layer, i think that this solution is cleaner than writing the loading mechanism directly to the entity class.

I am open to another suggestions or feedback

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just move this logic outside the post entity and event listener? If you know when you need to calculate the status you can do it explicitly.
For example

```
$post = $this->entityManager->find(BlogPost::class, $postId);
$status = $this->postHandler->calculateStatus($post);
```

The other approach I could suggest is not good but works. You could use lazy calculation and instead of calling `$this->postHandler->calculateStatus($this)` in postLoad event listener you could inject postHandler service into entity and perform the calculation in the moment you actually need it.
For example if you need calculation when calling `$blogPost->getStatus()` method, you could do it this way:

```
interface PostHandlerAwareInterface
{
    public function setPostHandler(PostHandlerInterface $postHandler): void;
}

class EntityServiceInjectorEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    /** @var PostHandlerInterface */
    private $postHandler;

    public function postLoad($entity): void
    {
        $this->injectServices($entity);
    }

    public function postPersist($entity): void
    {
        $this->injectServices($entity);
    }

    private function injectServices($entity): void
    {
        if ($entity instanceof PostHandlerAwareInterface) {
            $entity->setPostHandler($this->postHandler);
        }
    }
}

class BlogPost extends PostHandlerAwareInterface
{
    /** @var PostHandlerInterface */
    private $postHandler;

    private $status;

    public function setPostHandler(PostHandlerInterface $postHandler): void
    {
        $this->postHandler = $postHandler;
    }

    public function getStatus()
    {
        if (null === $this->status) {
            $this->postHandler->calculateStatus($this);
        }

        return $this->status;
    }
}
```

If you don't like this idea you still could manage it via (BUT I STRONGLY DO NOT RECOMMEND DO THIS DIRTY HACK) setting the flag to your entity event listener.
You could inject your entity event listener to the code and set flag before fetching data:

```
class BlogPostCalculateStatusListener
{
    /** @var bool */
    private $calculationEnabled = true;

    public function suspendCalculation(): void
    {
        $this->calculationEnabled = false;
    }

    public function resumeCalculation(): void
    {
        $this->calculationEnabled = true;
    }

    public function postLoad(BlogPost $post): void
    {
        if ($this->calculationEnabled) {
            $this->postHandler->calculateStatus($post);
        }
    }
}

$this->calculateStatusListener->suspendCalculation();
$blogPosts = $blogPostRepository->findBlogPosts();
$this->calculateStatusListener->resumeCalculation();
```

Hope this helps.

PS. If you want to get only the descriptions of all blog posts you can do this way:

```
class BlogPostRepository
{
    public function findBlogPosts()
    {
        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('bp.description')
            ->from('AppBundle:BlogPosts', 'bp')
            ->innerJoin('bp.website', 'w');

        return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
    }
}
```

`getArrayResult` does not invoke lifecycle callbacks.